How to override a Chisel constant with type of Vec?
Here's a class named RequestBuffer.
class RequestBuffer(flow: Boolean = true, entries: Int = 4)(implicit p: Parameters) extends L2Module {
  val buffer = RegInit(VecInit(Seq.fill(entries)(0.U.asTypeOf(new ReqEntry))))
  ...
}

Now I want to create a new class named UnifiedRequestBuffer which extends RequestBuffer.
So I tried following codes.
class RequestBuffer(flow: Boolean = true, entries: Int = 4)(implicit p: Parameters) extends L2Module {
  lazy val buffer = RegInit(VecInit(Seq.fill(entries)(0.U.asTypeOf(new ReqEntry))))
  ...
}
class UnifiedRequestBuffer(flow: Boolean = true, entries: Int = 4)(implicit p: Parameters) extends RequestBuffer {
  override lazy val buffer = RegInit(VecInit(Seq.fill(entries)(0.U.asTypeOf(new UnifiedReqEntry))))
  ...
}

Although UnifiedReqEntry extends ReqEntry, it doesn't work at all.
[error] .../UnifiedRequestBuffer.scala:40:45: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : chisel3.Vec[coupledL2.UnifiedCache.UnifiedReqEntry]
[error]  required: chisel3.Vec[coupledL2.ReqEntry]
[error] Note: coupledL2.UnifiedCache.UnifiedReqEntry <: coupledL2.ReqEntry, but class Vec is invariant in type T.
[error] You may wish to define T as +T instead. (SLS 4.5)
[error]   override lazy val buffer = RegInit(VecInit(Seq.fill(entries)(0.U.asTypeOf(new UnifiedReqEntry))))
[error]                                             ^
[error] one error found

Obviously, Vec[UnifiedReqEntry] and Vec[ReqEntry] dismatch here.
ChatGPT advices using covariant type here, but I didn't understand it.
I don't want to greatly change the base class.
How to achieve my goal with minimal change?

The issue is that on the chisel3.Vec class, the tipe parameter has not be declared as covariant.
Covariant means that the inheritance goes in the same direction of the type parameter inheritance, eg:
If B is a subclass of A than List[B] is a subclass of List[A], a function accepting List[A] can accept a List[B] as well.
To declare a type parameter covariant, you use the + sign before the type parameter: class MyClass[+A]{}
Contravariant is the opposite:
If B is a subclass of A than Option[B] is a superclass of Option[A].
To declare a type parameter contravariant, you use the - sign before the type parameter: class MyClass[-A]{}
